# Loading Animation while PHP loop runs

Tags: javascript, php, css, loading

I want to put a loading animation while php loop (for loop ) runs
Lets say it's a for loop with 10 numbers . I want to show an animation as
1 Loading.. when the seconds number starts it shows 2 Loading only (not both 1 & 2)
I hope you can understand my question properly .Can you please help me on this

```
 <html>
<head>
<style>
.loading:after {
  content: ' .';
  animation: dots 1s steps(5, end) infinite;}

@keyframes dots {
  0%, 20% {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    text-shadow:
      .25em 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0),
      .5em 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0);}
  40% {
    color: white;
    text-shadow:
      .25em 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0),
      .5em 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0);}
  60% {
    text-shadow:
      .25em 0 0 white,
      .5em 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0);}
  80%, 100% {
    text-shadow:
      .25em 0 0 white,
      .5em 0 0 white;}}


</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
</head>
<body>               
<?php
$i=0;
for ($i=0;$i <= 10; $i++)
{
  echo "  <p class='loading'>$i Loading</p>";
}
?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: PHP runs first then the generated source is feed to the browser. You'll need to use JS, maybe AJAX. Looping through numbers isn't something PHP is needed for JS has `for` as well.

Comment: Yeah Thanks for the information. But the issue is that in actual scenario i'm calling PHP function (PUT request) while running the loop.

Comment: How do i run a javascript loop while running a php loop sync

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it set up, what you want is not possible. That's because of how PHP works.

When PHP is embedded in an HTML file like that, it's run on the server before the page is sent to the user. The timeline goes like this:

1. The user requests the page
2. The server finds the file for that page
3. The server runs the code inside each  block and substitutes in the result for the php tag.
4. The server sends the generated HTML document to the user

As you can see, by the time the user sees anything, all the php code has already finished.

To get any kind of dynamic behavior in your webpage (*like a loading bar*) you HAVE to use JavaScript (or something that compiles to JS like TypeScript). That's because JavaScript code is sent to the user along with the HTML and executed *by the user's browser* after the page loads.

Presumably, you want to show a progress meter because you wanted to run some PHP code that would take a while. You can still do that. Instead of embedding PHP inside HTML, you can make a stand-alone PHP file that does the task you want and then have the JavaScript on your page send a second request to that server and get a result while showing its progress. The terms you want to google are "PHP REST server" (for the server) and "JavaScript XHR" or "JavaScript fetch" for sending requests from the client.