# datatable colour changing of rows based on condition in php codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, datatable, codeigniter-3

I'm working on the server side datatable in PHP Codeigniter where I want to change color of the rows based on condition (without page refresh). Please tell me the code to fix this.

In this datatable I want to color my row (conditional) when my filter button hit only, else same.

[image: view of the table]

I'm using this code:

```
$no = 0;
// echo "<pre>"; print_r($instock_products);
if(!empty($instock_products)){
foreach ($instock_products as $row) {
$id= $row->product_id;
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime ($row->expiry));
?>
<tr
style="<?php
//  if ($row->quantity < 15) {echo "color:red; background-color: gainsboro;";}
// else{
//  if ($date < 2022-03-15 ){echo "color:red; background-color: gainsboro;";}
if($row->quantity < 15 || $date < 2022-03-15 ){echo "color:red; background-color: gainsboro;";}
?>" >
```

My data is shown in red before the filter button run and I want to color red my table only when my filter button is hit and then as per conditon rows should colored.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard for me to understand what you are saying (maybe editing the question could get you some more useful answers?) but if I understand correctly, you want to change the appearance of the page using `php` *without* reloading the page. This is simple not possible. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61052567/loading-animation-while-php-loop-runs/61055492#61055492) for a complete explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Your need to check the data values before it is displayed as below.**

```
$color ="red";
$no = 0;
// echo "<pre>"; print_r($instock_products);
if(!empty($instock_products)){
foreach ($instock_products as $row) {
if($row->product_id<15){$color="pink";}
elif($row->date < 2022-03-15){$color="green";}
elif($row->product_id<15 ||$row->date < 2022-03-15 ){$color="blue";}

?>

<tr class="gradeA" style="background-color:<?php echo $color; ?>">
DISPLAY YOUR DATA HERE

</tr>
```